# How to embed a Laravel application within another web application?

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-routing, laravel-5, illuminate-container

So I have a web application, say www.randomwebapp.com, and I want www.randomwebapp.com/laravelapp to point to a laravel app I have written. I've already figured out how to include my laravel app as a separate package and access classes within my laravel app, but I'm wondering how to actually go about rendering views/routing etc. I'm mainly concerned with how to actually *start* running the app (perhaps something to do with bootstrap/app.php or bootstrap/autoload.php).

Comment: Ammm... Make directory "./laravelapp" and copy your laravel app then configure webserver rewrite_base for that directory.

Or I've not understood your question?

Answer (score 1):

I'm assuming you're using the boilerplate laravel installation folder structure provided by https://github.com/laravel/laravel, and your two apps are truly separate and have no dependencies on each other.

I'm also assuming folder structure looks something like this:

```
+ /webroot
  + /app
  + ( other laravel folders )
  + /public
  + /vendor
  + index.php
  + /other-site-dir
```

I would simply rename `public` to `laravelapp`. You may have to edit your `laravelapp/.htaccess` (formerly `public/.htaccess`) file to not redirect to your domain root and direct to `laravelapp/index.php` instead.

You may also have to rewrite our group all your routes into a `Route::group('/laravelapp'...);`

These are just off-the-cuff thoughts... If you have an example of your folder structure, it could help.

Comment: this was helpful thanks. I ended up solving the problem by moving the public folder out of the laravel app into the root directory of my main application.