# HTAccess redirect everything to folder except specific URL

Tags: laravel, .htaccess

I really dunno much about HTAccess, but here's what i have to do:

if the path is like `domain.it/installatori` then it will just call the pages within the `/installatori` folder

otherwise use existing code (which is what follows):

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^public
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ public/$1 [R=301,L]
</IfModule>
```

I know it's probably a dummy question with a really easy solution, but i just don't know it and can't find anything helping me

NOTE: the website is build with laravel and the other subwebsite in the `installatori` folder is another laravel website, each of these website have their own routing algorithm

Comment: Check this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28354734/how-to-embed-a-laravel-application-within-another-web-application)

Answer (score 3):

Change your rule to this:

```
RewriteEngine on

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/(public|installatori) [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ public/$1 [R=301,L]
```

And remember to clear your browser cache.

Answer (score 1):

based on the question.if your url is domain.it/installatori

```
 Options -Indexes

ErrorDocument 404 /404.php
ErrorDocument 403 /404.php


        RewriteEngine On
        RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^domain.it/installatori $
        RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/public/
        RewriteRule (.*) /public/$1
```